# How to Stop automatically creation of Term Set while migrating Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint online using ShareGate

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online

How can i stop migration or Validate and raise error/warning if Term Set is not available on destination using ShareGate.
I don't want automatically creation of Term Set by Share Gate, I am migrating Share Point 2010 to Share Point Online using Share Gate.

Comment: its site level migration or library/list  level?

Comment: Site level migration.